# Not able to login to Informatica admin Console

Tags: informatica

i have recently installed informatica on win7 but i am not able to login to admin console with Administrator/Administrator

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not able to get your exact problem.
I guess Your Informatica admin console is able to access using URL:localhost
If it is so then you have to use Id and password

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember the password you used while installing infa? If you are not administrator then you should connect him/her for that password. Then you can use Administrator/xxxxx to login.

Koushik

Answer (score 0):

The credentials might be wrong. Check the creds and try login.

Comment: This should be a comment